# How to fix the output for converting to JSON

Tags: python, json

I wrote a code in python that converts a file with these objects to JSON. It converts into the proper json format but the output is not exactly what I need.

```
{ 
    name: (sindey, crosby)
    game: "Hockey"
    type: athlete
},
{ 
    name: (wayne, gretzky)
    game: "Ice Hockey"
    type: athlete
}
```

Code:

```
import json

f = open("log.file", "r")
content = f.read()
splitcontent = content.splitlines()

d = []
for line in splitcontent:
    appendage = {}
    if ('}' in line) or ('{' in line):
        # Append a just-created record and start a new one
        continue

    d.append(appendage)
    key, val = line.split(':')

    if val.endswith(','):
        # strip a trailing comma
        val = val[:-1]
    appendage[key] = val


with open("json_log.json", 'w') as file:
    file.write((json.dumps(d, indent=4, sort_keys=False)))
```

Desired output:

```
[
    { 
        "name": "(sindey, crosby)",
        "game": "Hockey",
        "type": "athlete"
    },
    { 
        "name": "(wayne, gretzky)",
        "game": "Ice Hockey",
        "type": "athlete"
    }
]
```

But I'm getting:

```
   [
 {
  "    name": " (sindey, crosby)"
 },
 {
  "    game": " \"Hockey\""
 },
 {
  "    type": " athlete"
 },
 {
  "    name": " (wayne, gretzky)"
 },
 {
  "    game": " \"Ice Hockey\""
 },
 {
  "    type": " athlete"
 }
]
```

Any way to fix it to get the desired output and fix the {} around each individual line?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please try to think carefully about the logic of the code. How many times should `appendage = {}` happen? Why? How many times *does* it happen? Why? Also: please make sure to copy and paste "actual output" - the `json` standard library module definitely can't give you an output with misaligned braces and missing commas.

Comment: You can't be getting that result. You're using `json.dumps()` to create the output file, but the result you claim to be getting isn't JSON.

Comment: I think you just need `appendage = {}` inside the `for` loop. Otherwise there is only one copy which gets appended to `d` and you end up with the last contents repeated.

Comment: @Barmar: in what way is the actual output not `json`?

Comment: @quamrana it is missing commas between the array elements.

Comment: Ok, I assume that is a transcription error.

Comment: @quamrana I assume so, too, but why can't he just copy/paste instead of retyping?

Comment: @Barmar: Quite right. I thought copy and paste was 'de-rigueur`

Comment: BTW, you can use `json.dump()` instead of `file.write(json.dumps(...))`

Comment: Sorry, @learner22. Most of this is noise. Did you try moving `appendage = {}`?

Comment: my apologies, I should've copy pasted to make it clear but it is in the proper json format, I fixed it up

Comment: @quamrana I should've thought of that earlier oops. But moving `appendage ={}` into the for loop puts {} around each line and converts into json rather than each object block

Comment: @quamrana [
 {
  "    name": " (sindey, crosby)"
 },
 {
  "    game": " \"Hockey\""
 },
 {
  "    type": " athlete"
 },
 {
  "    name": " (wayne, gretzky)"
 },
 {
  "    game": " \"Ice Hockey\""
 },
 {
  "    type": " athlete"
 }
]

Comment: The comments aren't good for code. Please update your question instead.

Comment: @quamrana sorry about this, getting used to stack overflow but updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's usually a good idea to split parsing into simpler tasks, e.g. first parse records, then parse fields.

I'm skipping the file handling and using a text variable:

```
intxt = """
{ 
    name: (sindey, crosby)
    game: "Hockey"
    type: athlete
},
{ 
    name: (wayne, gretzky)
    game: "Ice Hockey"
    type: athlete
}
"""
```

Then create a function that can yield all lines that are part of a record:

```
import json

def parse_records(txt):
    reclines = []
    for line in txt.split('\n'):
        if ':' not in line:
            if reclines:
                yield reclines
                reclines = []
        else:
            reclines.append(line)
```

and a function that takes those lines and parses each key/value pair:

```
def parse_fields(reclines):
    res = {}
    for line in reclines:
        key, val = line.strip().rstrip(',').split(':', 1)
        res[key.strip()] = val.strip()
    return res
```

the main function becomes trivial:

```
res = []
for rec in parse_records(intxt):
    res.append(parse_fields(rec))

print(json.dumps(res, indent=4))
```

the output, as desired:

```
[
    {
        "name": "(sindey, crosby)",
        "game": "\"Hockey\"",
        "type": "athlete"
    },
    {
        "name": "(wayne, gretzky)",
        "game": "\"Ice Hockey\"",
        "type": "athlete"
    }
]
```

The parsing functions can of course be made better, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Yes I haven't checked the ouput properly, I remodified the logic now. The output is as expected.

```
import json

f = open("log.file", "r")
content = f.read()
print(content)
splitcontent = content.splitlines()
d = []
for line in splitcontent:
    if "{" in line:
        appendage = {}
    elif "}" in line:
        d.append(appendage)
    else:
        key, val = line.split(':')
        appendage[key.strip()] = val.strip()

with open("json_log.json", 'w') as file:
    file.write((json.dumps(d, indent=4, sort_keys=False)))
```

Comment: it strips the leading whitespaces, but I'm still getting the {} around each line, is there any way to remove those? Thank you